# Regular expression to separate values joined by a character in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have values where two numbers are separated by a character like '-'. Example,

```
123-456
98765-4321
1-2345
```

What I need is to separate the numbers that are before the '-' and after it in two different variables. So, for 123-456, I want to separate 123 into one variable and 456 into another.

How would I do this in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $string = '123-456';
my ($first, $second) = split /-/, $string;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
split(/-/, "123-456");   # => ("123", "456")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my ($before, $after) = /(\d+)-(\d+)/;
```